# Doctrine Query Builder Error on Join: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I am building a shipping system for an eCommerce site using doctrine. To do this I have get the appropriate shipping methods and prices based on product and region data in the checkout.

I am using the following code with the QueryBuilder:

```
        $shippingPriceReccords 
            = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('price')
            ->from('OrderShippingPrice', 'price')
            ->innerJoin('OrderShippingMethod', 'method', 'price.fkOrderShippingMethod = method.id')
            ->innerJoin('OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping', 'map', 'map.fkOrderShippingMethod = method.id')
            ->where('price.fkProductType = :fkProductType')
            ->andwhere('price.fkBrand = :fkBrand')
            ->andwhere('map.fkRegion = :fkRegion')
            ->setParameters([
                'fkProductType' => $fkProductType, 
                'fkBrand' => $fkBrand,
                'fkRegion' => $regionID,
            ])
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFetchMode("OrderCart", "address", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER)
            ->getResult();
```

But this is failing and giving me this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'
```

The DQL from the above query:

```
SELECT price FROM OrderShippingPrice price INNER JOIN OrderShippingMethod method INNER JOIN OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping map WHERE price.fkProductType = :fkProductType AND price.fkBrand = :fkBrand AND map.fkRegion = :fkRegion
```

OrderShippingPrice contains:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * OrderShippingPrice
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="orderShippingPrice")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrderShippingPrice 
{
    /**
     * 
     *  Normal string / int object data
     * 
     */

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fkOrderShippingMethod", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fkOrderShippingMethod = '0';   

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float", precision=7, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $price = '0.00';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fkProductType", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fkProductType = '0';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fkBrand", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fkBrand = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isExpeditable", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $isExpeditable = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="expediteDescription", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $expediteDescription = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="showLiftGateOption", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $showLiftGateOption = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="showDestinationOption", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $showDestinationOption = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="productNotAvailable", type="string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $productNotAvailable = '0';

    /**
     * 
     *  Relationship managment propperties
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Many OrderShippingPrices have One OrderShippingMethod.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderShippingMethod", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fkOrderShippingMethod", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $orderShippingMethod;

    /**
     * Get orderOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @return OrderShippingMethod
     */
    public function getOrderShippingMethod()
    {
        return $this->orderShippingMethod;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *  Normal string / int getters and setters
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @param string $fkOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setFkOrderShippingMethod($fkOrderShippingMethod)
    {
        $this->fkOrderShippingMethod = $fkOrderShippingMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFkOrderShippingMethod()
    {
        return $this->fkOrderShippingMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkProductType
     *
     * @param string $fkProductType
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setFkProductType($fkProductType)
    {
        $this->fkProductType = $fkProductType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkProductType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFkProductType()
    {
        return $this->fkProductType;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkBrand
     *
     * @param string $fkBrand
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setFkBrand($fkBrand)
    {
        $this->fkBrand = $fkBrand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkBrand
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFkBrand()
    {
        return $this->fkBrand;
    }

    /**
     * Set isExpeditable
     *
     * @param string $isExpeditable
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setIsExpeditable($isExpeditable)
    {
        $this->isExpeditable = $isExpeditable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isExpeditable
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsExpeditable()
    {
        return $this->isExpeditable;
    }

    /**
     * Set expediteDescription
     *
     * @param string $expediteDescription
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setExpediteDescription($expediteDescription)
    {
        $this->expediteDescription = $expediteDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expediteDescription
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExpediteDescription()
    {
        return $this->expediteDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set showLiftGateOption
     *
     * @param string $showLiftGateOption
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setShowLiftGateOption($showLiftGateOption)
    {
        $this->showLiftGateOption = $showLiftGateOption;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get showLiftGateOption
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShowLiftGateOption()
    {
        return $this->showLiftGateOption;
    }

    /**
     * Set showDestinationOption
     *
     * @param string $showDestinationOption
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setShowDestinationOption($showDestinationOption)
    {
        $this->showDestinationOption = $showDestinationOption;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get showDestinationOption
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShowDestinationOption()
    {
        return $this->showDestinationOption;
    }

    /**
     * Set productNotAvailable
     *
     * @param string $productNotAvailable
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setProductNotAvailable($productNotAvailable)
    {
        $this->productNotAvailable = $productNotAvailable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productNotAvailable
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductNotAvailable()
    {
        return $this->productNotAvailable;
    }
}
```

OrderShippingMethod contains:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * OrderShippingMethod
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="orderShippingMethod")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrderShippingMethod 
{
    /**
     * 
     *  Normal string / int object data
     * 
     */

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;    

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="carrier", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $carrier = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bvCode", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $bvCode = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="trackingUrl", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $trackingUrl = '';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="minimumLeadTime", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $minimumLeadTime = '0';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="maximumLeadTime", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $maximumLeadTime = '0';

    /**
     * 
     *  Relationship managment propperties
     * 
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping", mappedBy="orderShippingMethod", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER")
     * @var orderShippingMethodRegionMappings[]
     **/
    public $orderShippingMethodRegionMappings;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Create array for collection of orderShippingMethodRegionMappings
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orderShippingMethodRegionMappings = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get orderShippingMethodRegionMapping(s)
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOrderShippingMethodRegionMappings()
    {
        return $this->orderShippingMethodRegionMappings;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *  Normal string / int getters and setters
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param int $name
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set carrier
     *
     * @param string $carrier
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setCarrier($carrier)
    {
        $this->carrier = $carrier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get carrier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCarrier()
    {
        return $this->carrier;
    }

    /**
     * Set bvCode
     *
     * @param string $bvCode
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setBvCode($bvCode)
    {
        $this->bvCode = $bvCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bvCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBvCode()
    {
        return $this->bvCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set trackingUrl
     *
     * @param string $trackingUrl
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setTrackingUrl($trackingUrl)
    {
        $this->trackingUrl = $trackingUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get trackingUrl
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTrackingUrl()
    {
        return $this->trackingUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Set minimumLeadTime
     *
     * @param string $minimumLeadTime
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setMinimumLeadTime($minimumLeadTime)
    {
        $this->minimumLeadTime = $minimumLeadTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get minimumLeadTime
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMinimumLeadTime()
    {
        return $this->minimumLeadTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set maximumLeadTime
     *
     * @param string $maximumLeadTime
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setMaximumLeadTime($maximumLeadTime)
    {
        $this->maximumLeadTime = $maximumLeadTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get maximumLeadTime
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMaximumLeadTime()
    {
        return $this->maximumLeadTime;
    }
}
```

OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping contains:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="orderShippingMethodRegionMapping")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping
{
    /**
     * 
     *  Normal string / int object data
     * 
     */

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fkOrderShippingMethod", type="integer")
     */
    private $fkOrderShippingMethod = '0';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fkOrderRegion", type="integer")
     */
    private $fkOrderRegion = '0';

    /**
     * 
     *  Relationship managment propperties
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Many OrderShippingPrices have One OrderShippingMethod.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderShippingMethod", inversedBy="orderShippingMethodRegionMappings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fkOrderShippingMethod", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $orderShippingMethod;

    /**
     * Sets a new OrderShippingMethod and cleans the previous one if set
     * @param OrderShippingMethod
     */
    public function setOrderShippingMethod(OrderShippingMethod $orderShippingMethod) 
    {   
        $this->orderShippingMethod = $orderShippingMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Get orderOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @return OrderShippingMethod
     */
    public function getOrderShippingMethod()
    {
        return $this->orderShippingMethod;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *  Normal string / int getters and setters
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @param int $fkOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setFkOrderShippingMethod($fkOrderShippingMethod)
    {
        $this->fkOrderShippingMethod = $fkOrderShippingMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkOrderShippingMethod
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getFkOrderShippingMethod()
    {
        return $this->fkOrderShippingMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkOrderRegion
     *
     * @param int $fkOrderRegion
     *
     * @return OrderCart
     */
    public function setFkOrderRegion($fkOrderRegion)
    {
        $this->fkOrderRegion = $fkOrderRegion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkOrderRegion
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getFkOrderRegion()
    {
        return $this->fkOrderRegion;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an argument in the `innerJoin` method call. You have to do this :

```
$shippingPriceReccords 
            = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('price')
            ->from('OrderShippingPrice', 'price')
            ->innerJoin('OrderShippingMethod', 'method', 'WITH', 'price.fkOrderShippingMethod = method.id')
            ->innerJoin('OrderShippingMethodRegionMapping', 'map', 'WITH', 'map.fkOrderShippingMethod = method.id')
            ->where('price.fkProductType = :fkProductType')
            ->andwhere('price.fkBrand = :fkBrand')
            ->andwhere('map.fkRegion = :fkRegion')
            ->setParameters([
                'fkProductType' => $fkProductType, 
                'fkBrand' => $fkBrand,
                'fkRegion' => $regionID,
            ])
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFetchMode("OrderCart", "address", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER)
            ->getResult();
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) :

```
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('u.status_id', '?1'))
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1')
// Example - $qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1', 'g.id')
public function innerJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null);
```